# Acceder a una posicion especifica de un array

Tags: php

Estoy intentando entrar en la posición [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVIXl.png) especifica de mi array .
tengo esto pero me muestra todo los array

```
    foreach($row as $valor => $ar){
        $i=0;
        foreach($ar as $et => $value){
            echo " $value";
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

y me muestra esto: Cada uno es una posicion de array
[image: cada uno es un array]

estes es el resultado de  `var_dump($row)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el resultado de  `var_dump($value)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias poner que tienes en tu array?

Comment: es ese allí que esta en la imagen devuelve esos tres valores en sus posiciones

Comment: Si cada uno es una posicion como dices: `["2","0"," ","x",etc]` porque no accedes `$row[2]`? que seria vacio `" " `

Comment: es el segundo foreach pero si ya lo intente .. no muestra nada

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($row);` agrégalo a la pregunta y dinos qué valor es el que quieres obtener. Si quieres ir a un valor en específico del array no necesitas recorrerlo puesto que ya sabes el índice al que quieres acceder.

Comment: listo ya agrege  var_dump($row) y mostre su resultado la idea seria entrar a la posicio [2]

Comment: Si quieres estar accediendo a las posiciones de tu arreglo porque no haces un echo de tu $val[$i];? siendo $i el iterador de tu foreach.

Comment: si pero no puedo acceder a una posición especifica ejemplo $value[2] no muestra nada ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo logre resolver asi con condicionales

```
foreach($row as $valor => $ar){
        $i=0;
        foreach($ar as $et => $value){

            if($i==0){
                $idbanCuenta=$value;
            }
            if($i==1){
                $codigoB=$value;
            }
            if($i==2){
                $cuenta=$value;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
```